# XSLT: Getting the latest date

Tags: xml, xslt, sorting

I have a structure like this:

```
  <Info ID="1">
    ...
    <Date>2009-04-21</Date>
  </Info>
  <Info ID="2">
    ...
    <Date>2009-04-22</Date>
  </Info>
  <Info ID="3">
    ...
    <Date>2009-04-20</Date>
  </Info>
```

I want to get the latest date using XSLT (in this example - 2009-04-22).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Figured it out, wasn't as hard as I thought it will be:

```
        <xsl:variable name="latest">
          <xsl:for-each select="Info">
            <xsl:sort select="Date" order="descending" />
            <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
              <xsl:value-of select="Date"/>
            </xsl:if>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:value-of select="$latest"/>
```

Comment: When faced with a different date format(in my case dd-mm-yyyy) the following sort worked for me: `<xsl:sort select="number(concat(substring(Date,7,4),substring(Date,4,2),substring(Date,1,2)))" order="descending" />`

Comment: @RobertSmit, If I understand this (2.0) documentation correctly (https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#element-perform-sort), you can sort by multiple elements. Not a huge benefit in your case, but might offer flexibility in other problems, such as: <xsl:sort select="substring(Date,7,4)" order="descending"/> <xsl:sort select="substring(Date,4,2)" order="descending"/> <xsl:sort select="substring(Date,1,2)" order="descending"/>

Answer (score 8):

In XSLT 2.0 or later, you shouldn't need to sort at all; you can use [`max()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-3/#func-max)...

```
<xsl:value-of select="max(//Date/xs:date(.))"/>
```

Comment: Interesting. I did not know about the "/xs:date(.)"-casting. Until now, I only used xs:date(xy), but this style does not accept multiple elements. Is there a namy for this kind of casting?

Answer (score 6):

XSLT 2.0+: `<xsl:perform-sort>` is used when we want to sort elements without processing the elements individually. `<xsl:sort>` is used to process elements in sorted order. Since you just want the last date in this case, you do not need to process each `<Info>` element. Use `<xsl:perform-sort>`:

```
<xsl:variable name="sorted_dates">
  <xsl:perform-sort select="Info/Date">
     <xsl:sort select="."/>
  </xsl:perform-sort>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:value-of select="$sorted_dates/Date[last()]"/>
```

Comment: You should note that this is XSLT 2.0 and up.