# Get most recent date in xml records

Tags: xslt, biztalk

My data model is as follows:

```
<Club>
<Captain>
<Name></Name>
<DateOfBirth>15-01-1985</DateOfBirth>
</Captain>
<PlayingStaff>
<Player>
<DateOfBirth>14-01-1993</DateOfBirth>
</Player>
<Player>
<DateOfBirth>07-12-1975</DateOfBirth>
</Player>
<Player>
<DateOfBirth>11-11-1991</DateOfBirth>
</Player>
</PlayingStaff>
</Club>
```

I've tried using the answer given here: [XSLT: Getting the latest date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684894/xslt-getting-the-latest-date/684964#684964) but it isnt giving me any value.

I'm trying to get the youngest player to pass to an external function.

I'm doing this in Biztalk so I have to stick to XSLT1

My work so far is as follows:

```
<xsl:variable name="youngestPlayer">
            <xsl:for-each select="$ClubRoot/*[local-name()='PlayingStaff']/*[local-name()='Player']">
                <xsl:sort select="./*[local-name()='DateOfBirth']" order="descending"/>
                <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
                    <xsl:value-of select="DateOfBirth"/>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="IsYoungestPlayerUnderAgeLimit" select="externalfunctionreturningboolean">
            <xsl:element name="blahhh"><xsl:value-of select="$IsYoungestPlayerUnderAgeLimit"/></xsl:element>
            <xsl:element name="blahhh"><xsl:value-of select="$youngestPlayer"/></xsl:element>
```

This is part of a large template - I can't really change this, but the value of ClubRoot is "`<xsl:variable name="ClubRoot" select="/*[1]"/>"` to ensure I can read its child nodes.

I'm always getting

```
<blahhh>false</blahhh>
<blahhh/>
```

as my debug values... so i'm not picking up the value I expect

Can someone highlight where I've gone wrong?

From the data above, I'd expect the value of 14-01-1993 in my youngestPlayer variable. But its blank.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that XSLT1.0 doesn't really have the concept of dates, so you are effectively sorting by the **DateOfBirth** elements as if they were just normal strings. If you can be sure the dates always come in the format DD-MM-YYYY you could use string manipulation to sort by the year, month and day

```
<xsl:sort select="number(substring(DateOfBirth, 7, 4))" order="descending"/>
<xsl:sort select="number(substring(DateOfBirth, 3, 2))" order="descending"/>
<xsl:sort select="number(substring(DateOfBirth, 1, 2))" order="descending"/>
```

So, given the following XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
   <xsl:template match="/Club">
      <xsl:for-each select="PlayingStaff/Player">
         <xsl:sort select="number(substring(DateOfBirth, 7, 4))" order="descending"/>
         <xsl:sort select="number(substring(DateOfBirth, 3, 2))" order="descending"/>
         <xsl:sort select="number(substring(DateOfBirth, 1, 2))" order="descending"/>

         <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
            <xsl:value-of select="DateOfBirth"/>
         </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your XML, the following is output

```
14-01-1993
```

Comment: By using the translate() function, you can reduce the count of xsl:sort instructions from 3 to 1, AND simplify the `xsl:sort/@select expression` .

Answer (score 2):

The reason why the date sorting in your linked reference 'worked' was because it was in `yyyy-MM-dd` format, as opposed to your `dd-MM-yyyy` format.

An alternative to Tim C / Sean's proposal is to use C# script functions (since you are using BizTalk) to revert the date to a sortable one as per your link - but note that this is unlikely to be as performant as native xslt functions. Note also that you may need to use [msxsl:node-set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5302535/xsl-store-node-set-in-variable) on your variables to tell BizTalk's parser that this is a fragment .

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:userCSharp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/userCSharp"
                xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
                exclude-result-prefixes="userCSharp msxsl"
                >
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="ClubRoot" select="/*[1]"/>
        <xsl:variable name="orderedPlayers">
            <xsl:for-each select="msxsl:node-set($ClubRoot)/*[local-name()='PlayingStaff']/*[local-name()='Player']">
                <xsl:sort select="userCSharp:makeSortableDate(string(*[local-name()='DateOfBirth']), 'dd-MM-yyyy')" order="descending"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="node() | @*"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:variable>

        <xsl:variable name="youngestPlayerDOB">
            <xsl:value-of select="msxsl:node-set($orderedPlayers)[1]/DateOfBirth/text()" />
        </xsl:variable>

        <xsl:element name="blahhh">
            <xsl:variable name="IsYoungestPlayerUnderAgeLimit" select="userCSharp:externalfunctionreturningboolean($youngestPlayerDOB)" />
            <xsl:value-of select="$IsYoungestPlayerUnderAgeLimit"/>
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:element name="blahhh">
            <xsl:value-of select="$youngestPlayerDOB"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <msxsl:script language="C#" implements-prefix="userCSharp">
        <![CDATA[
        public System.String makeSortableDate(System.String yourDate, string format)
        {
            return (System.DateTime.ParseExact(yourDate, format, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
        }

        public bool externalfunctionreturningboolean(System.String dobString)
        {
            System.DateTime someDate;
            if (System.DateTime.TryParse(dobString, out someDate))
            {
                // NB : Doesn't work out leap years correctly!
                if ((System.DateTime.Now - someDate).Days < 21 * 365.25)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    ]]>
    </msxsl:script>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I've taken a hack at function and guessed that the underage limit is 21. The above returns

```
<blahhh>true</blahhh>
<blahhh>14-01-1993</blahhh>
```